# Convert All Values in a Column From VARCHAR to DATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, str-to-date

I know how using STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt); will change the format of a specific string, but if I have a column of all different dates in a text format (ex. 1/11/2016, 1/25/2016, 6/27/2015...) how do I convert all of the data in the column to DATE format? From everything I'm reading, it seems you need to provide the exact value to be converted each time.

Comment: so? `str_to_date(yourfield, '%d/%m/%Y')`, done. you can use fields in a record as part of the update query, e.g. `update foo set bar=bar+1` is completely legitimate/valid.

Comment: You are right - I was getting "NULL" in testing, but it does work: `update pp_drops_dev
set Create_Date = str_to_date(Create_Date, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple **ifnull** fuction for this.

```
select ifnull(STR_TO_DATE(a,'%Y-%m-%d'),sTR_TO_DATE(a,'%Y-%d-%m')) from [YourTable];

update [YourTable] set timestamp=ifnull(STR_TO_DATE([Colum],'%Y-%m-%d'),sTR_TO_DATE(a,'%Y-%d-%m')) ;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark B.

str_to_date(yourfield, '%d/%m/%Y'), done. you can use fields in a record as part of the update query, e.g. update foo set bar=bar+1 is completely legitimate/valid.

So I used:

```
update [My_Table]
set Create_Date = str_to_date(Create_Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```